# Wine installation not completing due to held broken packages

Tags: package-management, wine

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and I want to install wine.  This is the output of `sudo apt-get install wine`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I spend 4 hours and I have not made any progress. I don't get it. Here is how the dependencies looks like:

```
wine -> wine1.4
wine1.4 -> wine1.4-amd64
wine1.4-amd64 -> wine1.4-common
wine1.4-common -> wine1.4
```

I see a problem here.

Please help me.

Comment: It looks like you have a package manager problem that is preventing it from being installed in the first place, can you run a `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and post the results in your question?

Comment: Is this still a problem? I see a dependency loop...

Answer (score 8):

Type in terminal

> ```
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
> sudo apt-get purge wine*
> sudo apt-get install -f
> ```

You can install wine after it.

Comment: that message about "held broken packages" is very confusing indeed, because it is simply not true; synaptic cannot "fix" such packages by itself; neither we can list them because they did not exist; your solution still works on ubuntu 14.04, when I try to upgrade from wine1.7 to 1.8; but it may fail if you have like 'PlayOnLinux', so we have to first remove it and then wine; all working now, thx!

Answer (score 0):

found the solution.  Install "synaptic" from your software repository, and then use it to delete all your wine packages. Just search in synaptic for "wine", and then remove all of them.  Then you should be able to install wine again.

Comment: Good suggestion but it didn't help. The only wine thing i had installed was winetricks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still has this issue, but I had a similar issue, and the first answer here helped:
[Can't install wine (or ia32-libs) in Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210054/cant-install-wine-or-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-12-10-64-bit/210795#210795)

Briefly what you should do:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences
```

and insert the following lines:

```
Package: *       
Pin: release a=quantal*
Pin-Priority: 2012
```

enter ctrl+O to write the file. Pin-Priority must be greater than 1000.

Then you may downgrade the offending applications with:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I remark, that I had wine installed correctly, but unfortunately I installed Intel's driver update, and after that did I have this dependency issue.
Hope this will work!

Answer (score 0):

for me (got the exact same message with 13.04 32 bit)

`sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and *then* `sudo apt-get install wine` and the message went away...

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into the same problem, probably as an side-effect of `apt-get autoremove` which I shouldn't have done... This is an incomplete answer posted here in case someone finds it helpful.

I was **not brave enough to follow the `apt-get dist-upgrade` path** by downgrading the system (used daily in my job). Searching further, I found [a hint in the discussion under Launchpad bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.4/+bug/994309/comments/60) of the issue:

1. Download manually the packages constituting wine by running `sudo apt-get download wine1.4 wine1.4-common wine1.4-i386 wine1.4-amd64 wine-gecko1.4` ; they end up in the home directory.
2. Force-install them via the low-level command `sudo dpkg --force-all -i wine1.4-386_1.4-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb wine1.4-common_1.4-0ubuntu4.1_all.deb wine1.4_1.4-0ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb wine1.4-amd64_1.4-0ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb wine-gecko1.4_1.4.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb` -- it complained with *"dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested"* but got the job done.

After this, **wine 1.4 is installed and working**. However, the package managers (synaptic etc) report broken dependencies on the wine packages and **the updater is not functional** (shows red "no pass" sign and reports *"... pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages."*). Also, synaptic would remove the (seemingly broken) wine on any attempt to install other packages; the only way around is to use `apt-get install` on command line.

So in the end, this seems to be a dead end path. As far as I can tell, the only real fix will be when package maintainer addresses that Launchpad bugreport.

Answer (score 0):

Update the package index:

## sudo apt-get update

Install wine deb package:

## sudo apt-get install wine

Comment: Why do you think this will work?