# Dependency problems installing wine 1.5 on ubuntu 12.04 x64

Tags: 12.04, installation, 64-bit, wine

Trying user1261084 solution:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

Trying @eric-carvalho solution once more

```
$ apt-cache policy libgnutls26
libgnutls26:
  Installed: 2.12.19-1
  Candidate: 2.12.19-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.12.19-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.12.14-5ubuntu3.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.12.14-5ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

I was removed `ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` repository (Software Center > Edit > Software Sources > Other Software and manually remove) then went to Ubuntu Software tab and changed `Download from` to `Main Server` as user1261084 suggested.

after that I tried to downgrade `libgnutls26` to version `2.12.14-5ubuntu3.1`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgnutls26=2.12.14-5ubuntu3.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  gnutls-bin
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libgnutls26
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 459 kB of archives.
After this operation, 326 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libgnutls26 amd64 2.12.14-5ubuntu3.1 [459 kB]
Fetched 459 kB in 5s (86.8 kB/s)      
dpkg: warning: downgrading libgnutls26 from 2.12.19-1 to 2.12.14-5ubuntu3.1.
(Reading database ... 267654 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libgnutls26 2.12.19-1 (using .../libgnutls26_2.12.14-5ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libgnutls26 ...
Setting up libgnutls26 (2.12.14-5ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

it worked so:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  autopoint rpm librpmbuild2 librpmsign0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fonts-droid fonts-horai-umefont libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libcapi20-3
  libcapi20-3:i386 libcups2:i386 libexif12:i386 libgcrypt11:i386 libgd2-xpm:i386 libgif4:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgnutls26:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgphoto2-2:i386 libgphoto2-port0:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386
  libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386
  libkrb5support0:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libllvm3.0:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libopenal1:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386
  libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libtasn1-3:i386 libusb-0.1-4:i386 libv4l-0:i386
  libv4lconvert0:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxfixes3:i386
  libxinerama1:i386 libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 ttf-droid ttf-umefont wine-gecko1.4 wine-gecko1.4:i386
  wine1.4 wine1.4-amd64 wine1.4-common wine1.4-i386:i386 winetricks
Suggested packages:
  cups-common:i386 rng-tools:i386 libgd-tools:i386 libglide3:i386 gnutls-bin:i386 gphoto2:i386 gtkam:i386 krb5-doc:i386 krb5-user:i386
  libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386 gstreamer-codec-install:i386 gnome-codec-install:i386 gstreamer0.10-tools:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386 hpoj:i386
  hplip:i386 libsane-extras:i386 sane-utils:i386 libsasl2-modules-otp:i386 libsasl2-modules-ldap:i386 libsasl2-modules-sql:i386
  libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit:i386 libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal:i386 dosbox
Recommended packages:
  xml-core:i386 gettext:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  alien debhelper gettext gnome-common intltool intltool-debian po-debconf
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-droid fonts-horai-umefont libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libcapi20-3
  libcapi20-3:i386 libcups2:i386 libexif12:i386 libgcrypt11:i386 libgd2-xpm:i386 libgif4:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgnutls26:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgphoto2-2:i386 libgphoto2-port0:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386
  libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386
  libkrb5support0:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libllvm3.0:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libopenal1:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386
  libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libtasn1-3:i386 libusb-0.1-4:i386 libv4l-0:i386
  libv4lconvert0:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxfixes3:i386
  libxinerama1:i386 libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 ttf-droid ttf-umefont wine wine-gecko1.4
  wine-gecko1.4:i386 wine1.4 wine1.4-amd64 wine1.4-common wine1.4-i386:i386 winetricks
0 upgraded, 74 newly installed, 7 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 143 MB of archives.
After this operation, 408 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
...
Setting up wine1.4-common (1.4-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up wine1.4-amd64 (1.4-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up wine1.4-i386:i386 (1.4-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up wine1.4 (1.4-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up wine (1.4-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

Checking Wine version (Installed: 1.4-0ubuntu4.1)

```
$ apt-cache policy wine
wine:
  Installed: 1.4-0ubuntu4.1
  Candidate: 1.4-0ubuntu4.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.4-0ubuntu4.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.4-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
```

[full log here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2865713/ubuntu-wine-instalation-log)

Now I have wine 1.4 installed I added `ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` repository again and:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine1.5
(...)
$ apt-cache policy wine
wine:
  Installed: 1.5.13-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.5.13-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.5.13-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.4-0ubuntu4.1 0
        500 http://mirror.globo.com/ubuntu/archive/ precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     1.4-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://mirror.globo.com/ubuntu/archive/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
```

So finally I have wine 1.5 installed (^-^) 
thanks for [Eric Carvalho](https://askubuntu.com/users/65926/eric-carvalho) and [user1261084](https://askubuntu.com/users/88400/user1261084) help.

Comment: Similar question [wine-on-ubuntu-12-04-64bit-wine1-4](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153442/wine-on-ubuntu-12-04-64bit-wine-depends-wine1-4-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-in?rq=1)

Comment: Same question at [why-do-i-get-an-unmet-dependencies-error-when-trying-to-install-wine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138530/why-do-i-get-an-unmet-dependencies-error-when-trying-to-install-wine?rq=1)

Comment: Use Synaptic Package Manager or USC. Dont use command line.

Comment: Can you please split this up and post your solution as an answer to the question so that the next person can figure out exactly how to solve this problem?

Comment: Seems to be a prevalent bug, I am having it as well: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.4/+bug/994309
[https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.4/+bug/1004217](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.4/+bug/1004217)
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.4/+bug/934854

Comment: It is still in the edit history, click on the date next to "edited" "Sep 20 at 1:32" please do not add answers in your question, you can copy the text from the edit log, and post as answer.

Comment: I suggest you use Synaptic to remove your broken packages, as `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` suggests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that [multiarch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec) is not enabled. This can happen if you upgrade Ubuntu from a previous version instead of performing a clean installation.

Run the following in a terminal:

```
echo "foreign-architecture i386" | sudo tee /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
sudo chmod 644 /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
```

Then try to install wine again:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

If you still get dependency problems, maybe it's because of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gettext/+bug/975967). `wine1.5-amd64` recommends `gettext`, `wine1.5-i386:i386` recommends `gettext:i386` and both `gettext` conflict with each other. I managed to install `wine1.5` via `aptitude`, install it if it's not already installed (`sudo apt-get install aptitude`):

```
sudo aptitude install wine1.5 gettext:i386-
```

The trailing minus (-) will tell `aptitude` to remove (or skip installation of) `gettext:i386`.

**EDIT:**

You have `libgnutls26` version 2.12.19, probably installed from a ppa because the latest version available from ubuntu repos is 2.12.14. `wine` depends on `libgnutls26:i386`, which must be the same version as `libgnutls26`, but 2.12.19 is not available for installation. You can try to manually download and install `libgnutls26:i386` version 2.12.19, or remove the ppa that installed `libgnutls26` version 2.12.19.

Please run `apt-cache policy libgnutls26` and post the output. Maybe I can help you to find out a solution.

Comment: You're right I upgraded it from 11.10 but when I tried your solution I got almost same errors

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the dependency resolution bug regarding gettext. Answer updated.

Comment: I tried you edited solution but it shows a list of packges will be removed (I need skype) so I aborted it

Comment: This is more complicated than I thought. I'll run some tests in a VM and post a reply later.

Comment: Answer updated. Please run `apt-cache policy libgnutls26` and post the output.

Comment: I tried your edited solution and post the outputs.

Comment: Did you try to re-add wine ppa and install wine-1.5?

Comment: You should mark this as the accepted answer. http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I had no issues anymore after carrying out the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then I successfully tried

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

Comment: I tried again - Almost same errors

Answer (score 1):

Go to Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Software Sources > Other Software

and manually remove ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
Then go to Ubuntu Software tab, and change:

"Download from" to "Main Server"

Then..

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine
```

Worked for me, good luck!

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Comment: Changing sources wont help if the bugs were not fixed. the problem was with specifying dependencies as = instead of >=