# Why I'm not able to install wine on x64?

Tags: installation, 64-bit, wine, dependencies

I got broken dependencies which I'm not able to solve since I uninstalled Ubuntu 11.04 and updated to 12.04.1.

That's a fresh install =/

Is anyone facing the same issue or did I screw something up?

Comment: I think you messed something up.  Make sure everything is fully updated.  I have wine and wine64 installed on 12.04.1

Answer (score 1):

It's almost the same problem reported in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/153907/65926). There's a conflict in `wine` package dependencies. Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install wine gettext:i386-
```

This will skip the installation of conflicting package. For better explanation refer to my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/178860/65926) to that question.