# Can't fix broken packages using Synaptic (Broken Package: Wine1.4)

Tags: apt, wine, software-installation, synaptic

Ok so I am trying to fix a broken package in order to install wine. When I do "sudo apt-get install wine" I get:

```
sam@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install wine 
[sudo] password for sam:  
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are 
using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet 
been created or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  wine : Depends: wine1.4 but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I try "sudo apt-get install wine1.4"

```
sam@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.4 : Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
           Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
                       kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So someone told me to try Synaptic. Here is what I tried:

1. Searched wine
2. Right clicked wine1.4
3. Said I needed to mark other packages
4. Mark
5. I click Apply. It says, You have to fix broken packages first!
6. I do Edit>Fix Broken Packages I get this

   ```
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
   E: Unable to correct dependencies
   E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
   E: Unable to correct dependencies
   ```

I am really frustrated. I removed the Official Wine PPA and tried it I even tried

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Please help me :(

System: Ubuntu 12.10 64bit

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with Wine and 64bit systems. The solutions proposed here solves de problem:

- [Dependency problems installing wine 1.5 on ubuntu 12.04 x64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153907/dependency-problems-installing-wine-1-5-on-ubuntu-12-04-x64)

Comment: sam@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Doesnt work dude

Comment: what happens if you do:
sudo apt-get install wine1.5

Comment: Answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/153907/dependency-problems-installing-wine-1-5-on-ubuntu-12-04-x64