# wine install problem

Tags: 12.04, installation, apt, wine

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine
[sudo] password for hergul: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine wine1.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.4 : Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4-0ubuntu4.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine wine1.4 wine1.4-i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.4-i386:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.16.0) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgphoto2-2:i386 (>= 2.4.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 (>= 0.10.22) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 (>= 0.10.26) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: gettext:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libfontconfig:i386
                     Recommends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

and

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

I have tried to install with synaptic and aptitude install but it did not.

Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be due to some dependencies on 32 bit packages, try running `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` and then attempting the install again.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: That doesn't sound good... try sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch and see what happens.

Comment: and: sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch :  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: libgettextpo0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gtk2-engines:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gtk2-engines-murrine:i386  
.........................

Comment: Depends: libgettextpo0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gtk2-engines:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gtk2-engines-oxygen:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gvfs:i386 but it is not going to be installed
.........

Comment: i tried this solution:http://askubuntu.com/questions/153907/dependency-problems-installing-wine-1-5-on-ubuntu-12-04-x64?rq=1   but it did not