# Can't install wine

Tags: wine, dependencies

I've tried over and over, and over nothing seems to work. I always get this when I try to install Wine:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine1.4: PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~) but 1.16.1.2ubuntu7.1 is to be installed
         Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.4 is to be installed
         Depends: libgettextpo0 but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: wine1.4-amd64 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4) but 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4) but it is a virtual package
```

still nothing.

```
brian@brian-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get purge wine* && sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wine1.4_1.4-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wine1.4_1.4-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb'
E: Unable to locate package wine1.4-amd64_1.4-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wine1.4-amd64_1.4-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb'
E: Unable to locate package wine1.4-common_1.4-0ubuntu4_all.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wine1.4-common_1.4-0ubuntu4_all.deb'
E: Unable to locate package wine1.4-i386_1.4-0ubuntu4_i386.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wine1.4-i386_1.4-0ubuntu4_i386.deb'
E: Unable to locate package wine-gecko1.4_1.4.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wine-gecko1.4_1.4.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb'
brian@brian-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get purge wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wine is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

i don't get it, i had 10.04 and it worked find untill i got the upgrade to 12.04 LTS

Comment: It looks to me like you've got a PPA in your /etc/apt/sources.list file that won't let you install Wine from the Ubuntu Software Center. I'm not sure which PPA it is; I think it may be ppa:scottritchie/build-tests. I hope somebody can help you get this sorted out. Meanwhile take a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/210054/cant-install-wine-or-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-12-10-64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [this instructions](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) and downloading wine from the dedicated PPA.

Comment: still doesn't work, i get the same error message

Comment: @bclark pay attention to what version you are installing, try the 1.5 `sudo apt-get install wine1.5 -y`