# Kubuntu 12.10 - Do I have to install all the i386 packages in order to run wine on an amd64 machine?

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, kubuntu, 32-bit, versions

Actually I have several questions here, but the main problem I want to solve is that, I need to run wine1.6 on my amd64 machine, which installed Kubuntu 12.10 for now.

First thing I noticed was that, wine1.6 asked for installing wine1.6-i386 as well.  I asked corresponding questions here, and in kubuntu forum.  My conclusion was that, in order to install wine1.6-i386, I also need to install a lot of :i386 packages, like libc6:i386, libgstreamer0.10:i386, and so on.  Is that correct?

Then, if it is correct, I got problems installing libc:i386.  I added multiarch settings using:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

and added [arch=amd64,i386] after "deb " in all my source.list configuration files.  Of course I remembered to run:

```
apt-get update
```

Then I tried to

apt-get install wine1.6 wine1.6-i386 wine1.6-amd64

and put all the i386 packages it requested after this install commands.

Now I got error messages like:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.17-0ubuntu5) but 2.15-0ubuntu20.1 is to be installed
libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.15-0ubuntu20.1) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
libgl1-mesa-glx : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (!= 9.1.3-0ubuntu0.3) but 9.0.3-0ubuntu0.4 is to be installed
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-glx (!= 9.0.3-0ubuntu0.4) but 9.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed
```

......

It looks like the amd64 and i386 versions didn't match.

Installing ia32-libs and ia32-libx-multiarch I got the same problem, since it asked for libc:i386.

I have no idea how to go on.  Please help me.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer... at least a solution for me.

[Can't install wine (or ia32-libs) in Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210054/cant-install-wine-or-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-12-10-64-bit?rq=1)

I don't need to remove my ppas.  Using `/etc/apt/preferences` to assign Pin-Priority would solve the dependencies problems while installing `wine-i386`.  However, in some of my machines it would remove *almost all* kde packages and I need to re-install them back after installing i386 packages.